# Chart.js - Show new data on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am working on a webapp that will show daily work hours per month, and I want to show the first week then when the user clicks on a specific (next) button the chart will remove / clear the first week data and populate it with the next week’s data and so on…

Image to explain what I mean
[image]

**Note: I'm using http://www.chartjs.org**

---

**Update**

My codes

**HTML code**

```
<canvas id="work-time1" height="180"></canvas>
<button type="button"id="btn-next">Next</button>
```

**JS code**

```
    var workedHoursData = [5, 3, 5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 2];
    var week = [];
    var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('work-time1').getContext('2d'), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Worked hours",
                backgroundColor: '#4da2ff',
                borderColor: 'transparent',
                scaleOverride:true,
                scaleSteps:9,
                scaleStartValue:0,
                scaleStepWidth:100,
                data: week
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                  min: 0,
        max: 13,
        stepSize: 1,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

    });
var counter = 6;
$('#btn-next').click(function () {
  week = workedHoursData.splice(0, counter);
  counter += counter;
})
```

Comment: "And I want a facebook like app, can you help me?" see what's my point? We are not free workers here to do your job. We are here to help people when they are stuck in their code or when they want some advices on something, that mean you have to try on your own and then ask for help when you have a problem.

Comment: @Gatsbill I know what this website is, I'm not here to play or just to get free help as are you say! but I tried my own solutions but didn't work, and I searched for solution for hours but I didn't find starting point. anyway thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Then show us some code, we will be happy to help you.

Comment: @Gatsbill See my update :)

Comment: Did you try using ```chart.update();```  at the end of your ```$('#btn-next').click``` function ?

Comment: I did but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change data directly in chart object and then call update method of this object :

```
$('#btn-next').click(function () {
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = workedHoursData.splice(0, counter);
  chart.update();
  counter += counter;
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late, thank you a lot for your help. This is the starting point I wanted. Now do you still need a "facebook like app" :)

Comment: Glad it helped. yeah still, but I guess Facebook bis will have to wait for few more years ^^.